# English queries to GIS systems

Tags: data-request, geospatial, nlp, english

I'm building a system that tries to answer geospatial English questions such as "Where is the closest restaurant" or "How many historic sites are in the east of Nantes?". Underlying database is OSM. To improve my system I need more English questions. Does anyone know of any place/logs etc. where I might find such a collection of questions?

Comment: This is unhelpful, but you might try googling/researching NLP (natural language processing)-- that's the "term of art" for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if such a set of exact phrases exist, you will probably need to stitch together words and phrases, like `How many`, `where is the`, `historic sites`, `are in` etc.

You might start by looking at ConceptNet5

See:

https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki and

http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu

For example a search for `where is` gives:

http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/where_be